# HttpGet for accessing a url

Tags: c#, http-get

I would like to get infos from https://api.cqc.org.uk/public/v1/changes/location?page=1&perPage=1000000&startTimestamp=2021-09-18T02:33:20Z&endTimestamp=2021-09-19T02:33:20Z

I've written the folowing sintax, but it doesn't seem to work

```
[HttpGet("changes/location{page}&{perPage}&{startTimestamp}&{endTimestamp}")]
        public async Task<ChangesDetailsVM>GetChange([FromRoute] string page, string perPage,  string startTimestamp, string endTimestamp)
        {
            return await _cqcService.GetChange(page, perPage, startTimestamp, endTimestamp);
        }
```

From Postman I received the folowing error:

> Request to cqc/changes/location1&1000&9/20/2021 8:57:53 AM&9/21/2021 8:57:53 AM failed with status code NotFound Response: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }"

Any sugestions how can I improve my sintax?

Comment: Change the ``changes/location{page}&{perPage}&{startTimestamp}&{endTimestamp}`` to this ``changes/location``, and remove [fromRoute]

Answer (score 0):

if you use Routing can write this :

```
// route
[HttpGet("changes/location/{page}/{perPage}/{startTimestamp}/{endTimestamp}")]
// url
localhost:3055/changes/location/12/4534/2021-09-18T02:33:20/2021-09-19T02:33:20
```

but if you want use parameters name write this :

```
// route
   [HttpGet("changes/location")]

// url
localhost:3056/changes/location?page=121&perPage=1233&startTimestamp=2021-09-18T02:33:20&endTimestamp=2021-09-19T02:33:20
```